# How to create custom ToolStripProgressBar in C# Windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

How to create custom ToolStripProgressBar in C# Windows forms?

I want to create a progressbar with the style as continuos but in windows xp it is not possible..

So how can  I set owner draw  for this control ?

Comment: I dont know about the ToolStripProgressBars but it should be similar to overriting normal Progress bars. Microsoft says how to do it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323116
And CodeProject adds something too: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/colorprogressbar.aspx

Comment: yeah , I know how to customize normal progressbar but need how it is done for ToolStripProgressBar

Comment: Use the ToolStripControlHost class.

Comment: Thank u for letting me know about ToolStripControlHost class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you more Information on the ToolStripControlHost, I created a ProgressBar using this with the following code

```
public class ToolStripProgressBarC : ToolStripControlHost
{
    // Call the base constructor passing in a ProgressBar instance.
    public ToolStripProgressBarC() : base(new ProgressBar()) 
    {
        ((ProgressBar)Control).Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
    }

    public ProgressBar ProgressBarControl
    {
        get
        {
            return Control as ProgressBar;
        }
    }

    // Expose the ProgressBar.Value as a property.
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return ProgressBarControl.Value;
        }
        set { ProgressBarControl.Value = value; }
    }

}
```

I then added it to my tool strip like so.

```
ToolStripProgressBarC tsp = new ToolStripProgressBarC();
tsp.Value = 90;
toolStrip1.Items.Add(tsp);
```

You should be able to do any extra overriding that you want by adding extra functions to the "ToolStripProgressBarC" class.